# numpy and ctypes: dealing with views

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

I using ctypes to interop between C and Python+numpy. The code in both sides is written by me. Usually it works as expected, but I've encountered a weird bug I don't understand.

My question is: what's going on?

I'm working on Linux (Manjaro 16.10), with gcc 6.2.1. python 2.7.12 and numpy 1.11.2.

---

A simplified version of my C code:

```
void imp(double *M) {/*do stuff, assumes M is a 3x3 row-major matrix*/}
```

A simplified version of my Python code:

```
lib = ctypes.CDLL('path/to/lib.so')

def function(M):
    assert(M.dtype == np.float64)
    lib.imp(M.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)))

# Snippet 1: Doesn't work correctly, gives nonsense results.
print my_var.dtype  # prints 'float64'
print my_var.shape  # prints '(3, 3)'
function(my_var)    # the assert in function doesn't fail

# Snippet 2: Works correctly, gives the expected results.
my_var = my_var.astype(np.float64) # (!!)
print my_var.dtype  # The same...
print my_var.shape  # ...as in...
function(my_var)    # ...snippet 1
```

---

**UPDATE**

Replacing

```
my_var = my_var.astype(np.float64)
```

with

```
my_var = my_var.copy()
```

works just as well. Apparently, the source of the problem is the fact my_var is a numpy's view (I've checked this by printing my_var.base).

So my revised question is: what's the correct way for pass numpy arrays with ctype, if those arrays might actually be views? Is copying all the arguments before calling a c-function unavoidable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `numpy.ascontiguousarray` and related `numpy.as*` functions. These will make a copy if necessary to get your data into a nice form for your function, but if the arrays are all fine as they are, then they will be left alone.

Useful references:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html